# how convert simple form submit to ajax submit without loading page like add product to cart function

Tags: wordpress

how convert simple form submit to ajax submit without loading page like add the product to cart function
`  
">
">

```
                    <button  type="submit" name="addift_add_wl_btn_popup">Add to Wishlist</button>
                </form>
```

session

```
public function addify_get_sectiuon_btn() {
        $wl_p_id     = '';

            if ( isset( $_POST['addift_add_wl_btn_popup'] ) ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST['addify_wl_product_id'] ) ) {
                $addify_add_to_wl_pro = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST ['addify_wl_product_id'] ) );
            }
            $addify_wl_var1 = array();
         $addify_wl_var1 = WC()->session->get( 'addify_section_name' );
         if ( !empty( $addify_wl_var1) ) {
            $addify_wl_var2 =$addify_add_to_wl_pro;
            array_push( $addify_wl_var1 ,$addify_wl_var2);
            WC()->session->set( 'addify_section_name',  $addify_wl_var1 );
         } else {
            WC()->session->set( 'addify_section_name',  array($addify_add_to_wl_pro) );
         }
         // WC()->session->set( 'addify_section_name', null );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#In jQuery#
listen to form submit and attach this code.

Remember to add `event.preventDefault()'`

```
  $.post(
                    ajaxurl,
                    { action: 'action_registered_by_add_action', addift_add_wl_btn_popup: addift_add_wl_btn_popup, addify_wl_product_id:addify_wl_product_id  },
                    function( response ) {
                        //do something
                    }
                );
```

#In PHP#

````
//register ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ACTION_NAME', function(){
            //base stufs here
        } );
```--
###or###
````

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ACTION_NAME', [$this, 'method'] );

```
##EDITED##


    
    //add this register to handle both logged in and not logged in users
    
    //add_action( 'wp_ajax_addify_get_sectiuon_btn',array( $this, 'addify_get_sectiuon_btn'));
    //add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_addify_get_sectiuon_btn',array( $this, 'addify_get_sectiuon_btn'));
```

```
( function ( $ ) {
    $( function () {
        
        $( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
            jQuery( '.addift_add_wl_btn_popup_class' ).click( function () {
                alert( "ok" );
            } );
            
            $( '.addift_add_wl_btn_popup_class' ).click( function ( event ) {
                
                event.preventDefault(); //prevent default behaviour - you have must add function param named `event`

                /*
                *   if its *.js file you must localize script to add variable see more https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/190299
                *   if its *.php file you can do this dirty inline php inside script
                */
                let ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>"; // wp ajax url obtain by wc helper {{ admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) }}
                
                let addift_add_wl_btn_popup = $('#addift_add_wl_btn_popup').val(); // or anything else - value taken from form
                let addify_wl_product_id = $('#addify_wl_product_id').val();  // or anything else - value taken from form

                $.post( ajaxurl, {
                    action: 'addify_get_sectiuon_btn',
                    addift_add_wl_btn_popup: addift_add_wl_btn_popup,
                    addify_wl_product_id: addify_wl_product_id
                },
                function ( response ) {
                    //do something s
                } );
            } );
        } );
        
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: my j query is jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('.addift_add_wl_btn_popup_class').click(function(){
     // alert("ok");
    });

  jQuery('.addift_add_wl_btn_popup_class').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default behaviour
    $.post(
                    ajaxurl,
                    { action: 'action_registered_by_add_action', addift_add_wl_btn_popup: addift_add_wl_btn_popup, addify_wl_product_id:addify_wl_product_id  },
                    function( response ) {
                        //do something
                    });
  });

});

Comment: the bellow answer comments are not added to explain you can you please check ist

Comment: see my edit https://stackoverflow.com/a/64495643/4780438
sorry for bad formatting

Comment: very sorry to say it's not working  yet I m new in this field

Comment: the form submit button is here

Comment: <form method="post" id="adify_awwl_popform" action="">
      <input type="text" name="addify_wl_product_id" id="addify_wl_product_id" value="<?php echo esc_html(  $product_id  ); ?>">
      <button  type="submit" name="addift_add_wl_btn_popup" id="addift_add_wl_btn_popup_id" class="addift_add_wl_btn_popup_class">Add to Wishlist</button>
     </form>

Comment: accepted your answer with a little bit changes  its working but I m facing a  new issue is that I get only the first product not adding other if I clicked to add other

Comment: can you please help me in this scenario Thanks @Mateusz Będziński

Answer (score 0):

my jquery

hook

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_addify_get_sectiuon_btn',array( $this, 'addify_get_sectiuon_btn'));
```

hook call back is

```
public function addify_get_sectiuon_btn() {
        $wl_p_id     = '';

            if ( isset( $_POST['addift_add_wl_btn_popup'] ) ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST['addify_wl_product_id'] ) ) {
                $addify_add_to_wl_pro = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST ['addify_wl_product_id'] ) );
            }
            $addify_wl_var1 = array();
         $addify_wl_var1 = WC()->session->get( 'addify_section_name' );
         if ( !empty( $addify_wl_var1) ) {
            $addify_wl_var2 =$addify_add_to_wl_pro;
            array_push( $addify_wl_var1 ,$addify_wl_var2);
            WC()->session->set( 'addify_section_name',  $addify_wl_var1 );
         } else {
            WC()->session->set( 'addify_section_name',  array($addify_add_to_wl_pro) );
         }
         // WC()->session->set( 'addify_section_name', null );
        }
    }
```